# How to lock computer using VBA

Tags: vba

How to lock computer using excel VBA? 
Just in case, by "lock computer" I mean same effect when you do "start menu --> shutdown --> Lock".

Comment: Sorry, it is a duplicated one. "Simulate windowskey+L in visual basic" solves this qeustion as brettdj suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a x64 bit:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function LockWorkStation Lib "user32.dll" () As Long

Private Sub LockStation()
    LockWorkStation
End Sub
```

For x32 bit:

*I think it's like this, can't test as I don't have a 32bit pc.*

```
Option Explicit

    Private Declare Function LockWorkStation Lib "user32.dll" () As Long

    Private Sub LockStation()
        LockWorkStation
    End Sub
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot. James!

Comment: No problem RealLifePM, VBA is rather fun.